# VB.NET - Is there a way to get the name of one column in an MS Access table for a query used on any table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to get the name of a single column in a table and use that in a query for sorting.

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve would be as follow:

TableA has 2 columns: "FirstName" and "LastName".

I make a query to `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE LIKE [column 2 (LastName)]` (don't take this query too literally, please)

Then there is TableB with 2 columns as well: "FirstName" and "SurName". Second column name is different in both tables as seen.

I would have to change the query in the code to that of the column "SurName" for TableB.

I was wondering if there was a way to call out a column in any table and maybe store it in a variable and use it on the query so that it may be used "universally" by any tables that is used on?

I did search and came up with results of getting all the column names in a table. I'm trying to look for only one column name.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: would you prefer to reference the field by ordinal position instead of name?

Comment: I think so, yes. I mean what if the names differs, but the columns are in the same order? 

Like the ones I used as examples.

Comment: You can always refer to columns by their numeric ordinal position, starting with zero, instead of their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a specific column name from a datatable. It means, you will have to pass the informations first from db to datatable. Example:

```
Dim Con as New SqlConnection("ur connection str")
Dim da as New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [table]",Con)
Dim dt as New Datatable
da.Fill(dt)

Me.Label1.Text = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
```

Comment: Well it certainly helped me understand how to do about it. However when i try to run it, i get an error saying it can't find the column...which is weird to be honest :(

Comment: How many columns your table have? remember the count always starts at 0. It means, if you have 3 columns you can call it like dt.Columns(0).ColumnName, dt.Columns(1).ColumnName, dt.Columns(2).ColumnName. Maybe you can post your code here :)

Comment: Dim lastnamecol As String = dts.Columns(2).ColumnName. This is what i have for trying out the column as you mentioned earlier. The string query I'm trying to aim for is: "SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE '%" & lastnamecol & " LIKE '%" & TextBox3.Text & "%'"

Comment: would this work within a query? assigning the column name to a variable and then using that variable in the query?

Answer (score 1):

First, 'fix' the design to make things it easy for your users:

```
CREATE VIEW People ( family_name, first_name ) AS
SELECT LastName, FirstName
  FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT SurName, FirstName
  FROM TableB;
```

Then the query becomes obvious:

```
SELECT *
  FROM People
 WHERE family_name ALIKE 'Reg%';
```